# web.config rewrite complete URL

Tags: web-config

**Hi there,**

Just a simple question. I Have a Domain with path, let's say `exampleme.com`, and this page has a specific page: `exampleme.com/game.php`. Is there a way to completely rewrite the link to another domain on that page? So that `exampleme.com/game.php`becomes `game.com`?

I've tried this, but since I'm fairly new to the web.config rewrite module, I'm a bit clueless.

```
`   <rule name="Examplerule">
      <match url="http://game.com" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/game.php" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite works only on your current domain. You need an redirect.

```
<rules>
  <rule name="Game" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="/game.php" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://game.com" />
  </rule>
 </rules>
```

Comment: I Need to stay on the same page without redirecting. Is that possible?

Comment: If the redirected Domain points to your Web Application - it is possible that the same server handles your customer. But all the cookies are not longer valid. This means that your Customer must sign in again, ... But without redirect it is not possible.